# Get set of keys having same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have javascript object array:

```
objArray = [
  {"date":"07/19/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"1000","code":"K100"},
  {"date":"07/21/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"899","code":"C835"},
  {"date":"07/23/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"700","code":"C837"},
  {"date":"07/23/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"800","code":"K100"},
  {"date":"07/23/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"50","code":"C837"}
];
```

I want to get all values of key date having same values as below

- removing duplicate date values
- combining the code values as array
- sum up the count value of duplicate date values

Here's the expected output:

```
newObjArray = [
  {"date":"07/19/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"1000","code":"K100"},
  {"date":"07/21/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"899","code":"C835"},
  {"date":"07/23/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"1550","code":["C837","K100","C837"]}
]
```

There's the way I have tried but could get the expected output. Anyone who can help me in processing me to get the desired output.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rs2vkwau/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
objArray = [
  {"date":"07/19/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"1000","code":"K100"},
  {"date":"07/21/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"899","code":"C835"},
  {"date":"07/23/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"700","code":"C837"},
  {"date":"07/23/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"800","code":"K100"},
  {"date":"07/23/2017 12:00:00 AM","count":"50","code":"C837"}
];


var objs = objArray.reduce((obj, rec) => {
  if (obj[rec.date] === undefined) {
    rec.code = [rec.code];
    rec.count = Number(rec.count);
    obj[rec.date] = rec;
  } else {
    obj[rec.date].count += Number(rec.count);
    obj[rec.date].code.push(rec.code);
  }
  return obj;
}, {}) 

console.log(Object.values(objs));
```